# running into issues with getting a taskRunner to run

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm working on a task runner that when loaded into node.js can take commands to run certain functions, for example making a number positive or negative, I need to be able to execute the code and be able to set different start values and the number used at the start has to be the number that gets changed when the functions are called.

I've looked around online and found another post called arithmaticTaskRunner which looks similar to something I need but doesn't explain or show how I would use the start value when calling the functions nor does it explain how to get the mathematical functions to work.

```
class TaskRunner {
constructor()
{
    this.tasks = [];
}
static set taskCount(counter)
{
    throw new('readonly, Value${value}');
}
addNegationTask()
{
    this.tasks.push()
}
addAdditionTask() 
{
    this.tasks.push();
}
addMultiplicationTask() 
{
    this.tasks.push();
}
run(startValue) 
{
    return this.tasks.reduce((x, fn) => fn(x), startValue);
}
}
let taskRunner = new taskRunner()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask()
taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask()
taskRunner.addAdditionTask()
```

This should be the outcome when the TaskRunner is loaded and functions are called in node.js, I don't have a full understanding of node.js at the moment and looking online to learn

```
> let taskRunner = new ArithmeticTaskRunner()
undefined
> taskRunner.addAdditionTask(2)
undefined
> taskRunner.addMultiplicationTask(4)
undefined
> taskRunner.addAdditionTask(10)
undefined
> taskRunner.execute(2)
26
> taskRunner.execute(-2)
10
```

but when I load the file into node.js all I get is the whole file loading in and the terminal showing everything in the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using some concepts from Builder pattern for an OperationExecutor class.
Builder allows you to construct something step by step and at the end you can get the result.

```
class OperationExecutor {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value; //value is the initial number on which we operate
    }


    add(valueToAdd) {
        this.value += valueToAdd;
        return this.value;
    }

    multiply(multiplyBy) {
        this.value = this.value * this.multiplyBy;
        return this.value;
    }

    getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
 }
 var operationExecutor = new OperationExecutor(2);
 operationExecutor.add(4);
 operationExecutor.multiply(5);
 console.log(operationExecutor.getValue());
```

All calls are sync, since you can not run a task without knowing the value the previous one computed.

A better way is to create a class Integer, which has the operations add/multiply/divide/sub/modulo etc. and a method getValue(). This way, it is clear for everyone the way you are planning to use those objects. The basic idea is the same.

Comment: I'm looking over the code that you have provided in the section above, I probably would be best to have it in separate classes, but the issue I have is that it all has to be in one class called taskRunner.

Comment: Here is roughtly what i have to get working with the code.
I need to implement a task array which i have already, then set up the anonymous functions that i have in the top section of my question for each mathmatical equation.

Comment: if I'm trying to push each of the mathematical functions into an array would i insert the equation inside the brackets of the "this.task.push() or before or after